# How do I secure a static HTML file in Django? (Make login required before redirecting)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-authentication, django-deployment

I am using Django Admin interface to allow the admin to upload html files, which will then be stored in 'static/notebooks/*file_name*'.

With the code below I am able to redirect, however how do I make login required and check for user permissions before redirecting? I can't use login required decorator since the static html file does not have a view or template associated with it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" style="margin: 1rem;"onclick="location.href='{% static 'notebooks/BrightspaceGradebookUsage.html' %}'">Python notebooks</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if user is authenticated, try:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" style="margin: 1rem;" {% if user.is_authenticated %} onclick="location.href='{% static 'notebooks/BrightspaceGradebookUsage.html' %}'" {% endif %}>Python notebooks</button>
```

Comment: In this case, the user can still manually type in the link and have access to it.